# Analyzing the speed-up of Oracle's HotSpot versus other compilation techniques

Tags: jvm, g++, jvm-hotspot

I'm currently working on a project that must involve research of JIT techniques. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to anything related to compilers but I did some research and learned about Java's Hotspot VM. I was hoping to do an analysis on the benefits (or downsides) of using Hotspot versus traditional compilers (for example, g++).

My initial idea was to create some sort of simple program that can be run through both compilers in order to compare compilation times but this brought up a number of questions:

- From my understanding, Java source code is initially turned into bytecode by the javac compiler (creating .class files) and then, in turn, this bytecode can be run through HotSpot at runtime to execute the program. Given this, would it even be relevant to compare results with a traditional compiler that converts sources directly to machine code?
- Another concern I'm facing is that the programs would be in different languages (ex. C++  vs Java). Although the functionality would be identical, could this skew results when attempting to compare?

Moving on, if the above two points are not a problem, my main questions is:

**How can I actually go about benchmarking the speed-up in one method versus the other?**

I did some brief research about this but all I was able to find were ways to measure the efficiency of the program itself, not the compilation technique used to run it. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Are there methods to actually analyze the speed up of one compiler over another?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Four links you may find interesting: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org https://godbolt.org http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/ https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch

Comment: Well, deciding what to compare and how to compare and which comparison makes sense, is exactly part of the work you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I actually go about benchmarking the speed-up in one method versus the other?

You first need to consider what you actually intend to measure. In other words, saying "the speed-up" is not sufficiently rigorous.

Are we talking about CPU cycles spent compiling? Or walltime from source code to running program? Or peak performance of a few critical methods in a micro benchmark? Overall steady-state program performance? Speed of program initialization? ...

In the end you're comparing two systems that made quite different trade-offs. You can find a few roughly comparable benchmarks already mentioned in the comments but in the end they mostly represent a specific type of throughput-bound tasks and not large applications. It's not like you can find an application such as firefox written both in C and Java with identical feature sets and comparable code quality. So any comparison you do will be incomplete because you'll have to use some limited proxy measurement of how comparable two code-bases are when you compare them.